# Detecting empty places on reversi board using javascript

Tags: javascript, reversi

I was developing a Reversi (Othello) game and I faced a scenario which I was going to detect empty places on the board.  I wrote it but it's not exact.

```
var IsUserTurn = true;
var Empty;

function InsertBlack(x, y) {
    var Temp1 = document.createElement("img");
    Temp1.setAttribute("src", "http://www.uploadhosting.co/uploads/151.238.149.6/Black.png");
    Temp1.style.position = "absolute";
    var Temp3 = (x * 50) - 50;
    var Temp4 = (y * 50) - 50;
    Temp1.style.left = Temp3 + "px";
    Temp1.style.top = Temp4 + "px";
    var Temp2 = document.getElementById("panel");
    Temp2.style.position = "relative";
    Temp2.appendChild(Temp1);
}

function InsertWhite(x, y) {
    var Temp1 = document.createElement("img");
    Temp1.setAttribute("src", "http://www.uploadhosting.co/uploads/151.238.149.6/White.png");
    Temp1.style.position = "absolute";
    var Temp3 = (x * 50) - 50;
    var Temp4 = (y * 50) - 50;
    Temp1.style.left = Temp3 + "px";
    Temp1.style.top = Temp4 + "px";
    var Temp2 = document.getElementById("panel");
    Temp2.style.position = "relative";
    Temp2.appendChild(Temp1);
}

function SetClickEventListenerForPanel() {
    var Temp1 = document.getElementById("panel");
    if (Temp1.addEventListener) {
        Temp1.addEventListener("click", PanelClickProcessor);
    } else if (Temp1.attachEvent) {
        Temp1.attachEvent("onclick", PanelClickProcessor);
    }
}

function SetBooleanVariableStatus() {
    if (IsUserTurn === true) {
        document.getElementById("Boolean").innerHTML = "User's turn";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("Boolean").innerHTML = "Computer's turn";
    }
}



function IsEmpty(x, y) {
    var Temp1 = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var i;

    var xx, yy;
    xx = (x * 50) - 50 + ("px");
    yy = (y * 50) - 50 + ("px");

    for (i = 0; i < Temp1.length; i++) {

        if (Temp1[i].style.left != xx && Temp1[i].style.top != yy) {
            Empty = true;
        } else {
            Empty = false;
            break;
        }


    }

    return Empty;

}

function Convert(data) {
    if (data <= 50) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (data <= 100) {
        return 2;
    }
    if (data <= 150) {
        return 3;
    }
    if (data <= 200) {
        return 4;
    }
    if (data <= 250) {
        return 5;
    }
    if (data <= 300) {
        return 6;
    }
    if (data <= 350) {
        return 7;
    }
    if (data <= 400) {
        return 8;
    }
}

function PanelClickProcessor(e) {
    var X = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    var Y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

    var xtocall, ytocall;

    xtocall = Convert(X);
    ytocall = Convert(Y);



    alert(IsEmpty(xtocall, ytocall));

}

InsertBlack(4, 4);
InsertWhite(5, 4);
InsertWhite(4, 5);
InsertBlack(5, 5);
SetClickEventListenerForPanel();
SetBooleanVariableStatus();
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/huL3qoa3

When you click anywhere on the board, an alert will be shown that, if the position is empty or not.  It is not working well, what's the problem?

Comment: Post your code in your question please. You saw the warning when you posted your question with only a link to jsFiddle.

Comment: I'm so sorry @j08691 but i don't know where the problem is? i don't know why doesn't it work? excuse me!

Comment: a big thanks to Rocket Hazmat for his edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `||` operator instead of the `&&` operator when you compare the coordinates:

```
if (Temp1[i].style.left != xx || Temp1[i].style.top != yy) {
```

Comment: That worked! thank you,i don't know how to thank you for this help. :D

Comment: Now i get that a simple operator can break down a big application!